# Error in IE8 while file upload is going on and trying to reset the uploader

Tags: fine-uploader

When we try to reset fineuploader while upload is going on IE8 we are encountering one error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'fileState[...].input' is null or not an object". It is happening in jquery.fineuploader-3.8.2. This issue is not happening in jquery.fineuploader-3.6.4.

Answer (score 0):

This may have been an issue fixed in 3.9.x (as there have been many `reset` issues fixed recently), but it's a fairly unusual workflow.  You have two options:

1. Upgrade to 3.9.x and see if the issue is fixed.
2. Call the `cancelAll` [method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/methods.html) before you call `reset` when uploads are in progress.